# Can't select column name from Eloquence database that has a forward slash in it (from a linked server in SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, linked-server

My SQL Server instance has a linked server to an Eloquence  database. I need to select data from one of the tables in the Eloquence database, but I need to do it with SQL syntax, since I'm running the code *from* [SQL Server Management Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio) (SSMS).

One of the columns has a forward slash in its name (I didn't create it, nor do I have the authority to change it), which throws the following syntax error when I run my query:

> OLE DB provider [ProviderName] for linked server [LinkedServerName] returned message "Prepare: Syntax error or access violation {Syntax error in item list (select).}".
>
> OLE DB provider [ProviderName] for linked server [LinkedServerName] returned message "Prepare: Syntax error or access violation {Expression syntax error in aggregate function.}".
>
> Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
> An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT [TableName.ColumnName/WithForwardSlash] FROM [TableName]" for execution against OLE DB provider [ProviderName] for linked server [LinkedServerName].

I have tried:

- `Select * from....` throws the same error
- Aliasing the column...throws the same error
- Selecting the tablename.column name...throws the same error
- Enclosing column name in brackets...throws the same error
- Escaping the forward slash...throws 'Column not found' error

Note:  I lack permissions to access the server directly, so I must query it via the linked server from SQL Server.

How can I select this column from SSMS via the linked server if it has a forward slash in it?  How can I get around this error?

The SQL/R documentation: *[SQL/R A.03 Documentation](http://www.marxmeier.com/sqlr/docs.html)*

Comment: Did you try selecting `[TableName].[ColumnName/WithForwardSlash]`?

Comment: If Malk's suggestion does not work try escaping the slash with two of them (ie `//`)

Comment: I have already tried both of those and neither worked.  I will update my question.

Comment: Because it throws a syntax error - but when I try escaping it it says 'Invalid Column Name', that tells me that it understands that the column with a forward slash in its name does in fact exist.  However, I think the SQL syntax is being converted to run against the eloquence database - and it is unable to convert the column name that has the forward slash.  That's probably why SELECT * from...throws the same error.

Comment: Can you create (or have someone else create) a view on the SQL Server and alias the column name in the view, then query that view instead of the table?

Comment: Creating a view will result in the same exact error, since the view needs to run the same query that I'm running in order to return a result set, right?  I have full SA permissions on the SQL Server, so I can do whatever I want there.  But I cannot access the eloquence database except via the linked server in SQL server.

Comment: Have you tried bringing it in through Excel and seeing what the results of that query is? http://www.marxmeier.com/sqlr/A0300/windows_odbc.html

Comment: @TTeeple As I said in the post, I cannot access the server directly, so that is an impossibility.

Comment: Have you tried using [`OPENQUERY()` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427(v=sql.100).aspx)?  Many third party clients require it for linked servers.

Comment: @BaconBits I tried that and it threw the same error - thank you for the suggestion, though, that was a new one!